# Facebook - Session is null after the phone reboot

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

After the phone reboot I have to relogin in my app, but I'd like not to do it. Is it possible to save facebook session in order to not relogin?

Comment: Yes it is possible to save the Facebook session. Facebook sdk has the complete implementation to save the session. By calling the below method you can check the session is valid or not.

public static boolean restore(Facebook session, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session.setAccessToken(savedSession.getString(TOKEN, null));
        session.setAccessExpires(savedSession.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return session.isSessionValid();
    }

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to save the Facebook session. Facebook sdk has the complete implementation to save the session. By calling the below method you can check the session is valid or not.

```
public static boolean restore(Facebook session, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences savedSession =
            context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session.setAccessToken(savedSession.getString(TOKEN, null));
        session.setAccessExpires(savedSession.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return session.isSessionValid();
    }
```